# How to make center area full viewport height minus dynamic height areas (flexbox)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How to do this without using fixed heights anywhere. This way, the `<div>` area is scrollable and the sections each take up the full visible height.  But the nav elements are fixed.

One way to do this is `calc(100vh - dynamic heights)` but looking for a non-hardcoded way of doing it.

```css
* {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body, header, section, footer {
  display: flex;
}

body, div {
  flex-direction: column;
}

section {
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid pink;
}

footer {
  height: 200px; /* just for demo purposes */
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px; /* just for demo purposes */
  background: orange;
}

div {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>

</header>
<div>
  <section>

  </section>
  <section>

  </section>
  <section>

  </section>
</div>
<footer>

</footer>
```

Comment: By meaning "a non-hardcoded way" do you mean it is set by the user? Wouldn't Javascript not be better for this?

Comment: Looking for a way to do it without JavaScript and so heights like 50px are not explicitly defined (and duplicated). It can be accomplished for 1 section without JavaScript, but not sure how to do it with more than 1.

Comment: @Lance Wouldnt you not use methods like `findElementById` for this? If that's not it, I'm left confused. Do you have an example of what your website should look like? I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify that code a little, and the 2 key settings are `flex: 1` on the `div` (which you already have) and `flex-shrink: 0` on `section`.

The `flex: 1` makes the `div` to fill available space without take its own content into account, and the `flex-shrink: 0` will prevent the `section`'s to *shrink-to-fit*.

I also changed from `100%` on `height` to `100vh`, so one doesn't need to repeat it down the line.

*Tested with success on Chrome, Firefox, Edge and IE11, and I also removed some unnecessary properties, like `width: 100%`, and all fixed `height`'s.*

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/031y8hrm/4/)

Stack snippet

```css
* {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  height: 100vh;
}
body, div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
div {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
section {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid pink;
}
footer {
  padding: 10px;
  background: yellow;
}
header {
  padding: 10px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<header>
 A header which<br>
 has 2 line of text
</header>
<div class="content">
  <section>
   1
  </section>
  <section>
   2
  </section>
  <section>
   3
  </section>
</div>
<footer>
 A footer which<br>
 has more lines of<br>
 text than the<br>
 header has and<br>
 it size nicley
</footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it

```css
* {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body,
section {
  min-height: 100vh; /* make the body and sections the height of the viewport */
  overflow: hidden;
}

body { /* only the body needs to be flex - you don't want everything to be otherwise you will have ie / safari problems with nested flex */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main {
  /* min-height: 100px; - you can add a min height here if you want so you don't get a situation where this middle section doesn't show up */
  flex-grow: 1;  /* grow the main to be the rest of the height */
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  position: relative;
}

.scroll {  /* add a scrollable div for your sections */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  overflow:auto;
}

footer {
  height: 200px; /* this can be removed if you want */
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;       /* this can be removed if you want */
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<header>

</header>
<div class="main">
  <div class="scroll">
    <section>

    </section>
    <section>

    </section>
    <section>

    </section>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>

</footer>
```

After comments:

```css
* {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  /* make the body the height of the viewport */
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  /* only the body needs to be flex - you don't want everything to be otherwise you will have ie / safari problems with nested flex */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main {
  /* min-height: 100px; - you can add a min height here if you want so you don't get a situation where this middle section doesn't show up */
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* grow the main to be the rest of the height */
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  position: relative;
}

.scroll {
  /* add a scrollable div for your sections */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  height:100%;
  overflow:auto;
}

section {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  min-height:100%;
}

footer {
  height: 200px;
  /* this can be removed if you want */
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  /* this can be removed if you want */
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<header>

</header>
<div class="main">
  <div class="scroll">
    <section>

    </section>
    <section>

    </section>
    <section>

    </section>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>

</footer>
```

Comment: This is just about it, thank you. But what I meant by sections taking up viewport height are they only take up the visible height.

Comment: Sorry my description is horrible. The first one was closer. Hoping to get the sections each to be the visible height, so when you scroll each one takes up the full visible height. The first one had each take up 100vh, the second had all 3 take up the visible height together. How to make each one take up visible height.